Combine two dataframes with scalable columns by placing the second dataframe directly below the first dataframe without deleting the keys
Here are my 2 dataframes that I have:
Code:
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'Key1': ['Value1'], 'Key2': ['Value2'], 'Key3': ['Value3'], 
         'Key4': ['Value4'], 'Key5': ['Value5']}

data2 = {'Key1': ['Value1', 'Value4'], 
         'Key4': ['Value2', 'Value5'], 
         'Key7': ['Value3', 'Value6']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

Dataframe 1:
Key1    Key2    Key3    Key4    Key5
Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4  Value5

Dataframe 2:
Key1    Key4    Key7
Value1  Value2  Value3
Value4  Value5  Value6

Expected Results:
Key1    Key2    Key3    Key4    Key5
Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4  Value5
Key1    Key4    Key7    NaN     NaN
Value1  Value2  Value3  NaN     NaN
Value4  Value5  Value6  NaN     NaN

How can I join both of these dataframes without merging the keys at all?

Please provide your input DataFrames as code, it's currently ambiguous if the header is a real header or a row, which would change the logic. Assuming df1/df2, please [edit] your question to add the output of df1.to_dict('tight') and df2.to_dict('tight').

Also you need to explain the format of your expected result. Is the Key 1 ... Key 5 line a header with column names or just a row of data within the final DF?  How is the process useful for any future use?

Assuming your input DataFrames have Key1/Key2/… as column headers, you can first move those to rows, then concat.
For that, two options, transpose and reset_index (which can be problemantic depending on the data types):
dfs = [df1, df2]

out = pd.concat([d.T.reset_index().T for d in dfs], ignore_index=True)

Or use a double concat:
dfs = [df1, df2]

out = pd.concat([pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([d.columns]),
                            pd.DataFrame(d.to_numpy())])
                 for d in dfs],
                ignore_index=True)

Reproducible input:
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Key1': ['Value1'], 'Key2': ['Value2'], 'Key3': ['Value3'],
                    'Key4': ['Value4'], 'Key5': ['Value5']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Key1': ['Value1', 'Value4'],
                    'Key2': ['Value2', 'Value5'],
                    'Key3': ['Value3', 'Value6']})

Output:
        0       1       2       3       4
0    Key1    Key2    Key3    Key4    Key5
1  Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4  Value5
2    Key1    Key2    Key3     NaN     NaN
3  Value1  Value2  Value3     NaN     NaN
4  Value4  Value5  Value6     NaN     NaN


I wasn't quite paying attention to certain parts of your code, but it seems like this code solves my problem.

Here is your desired solution ->
import pandas as pd

data1={'Key1':['value1'],'Key2':['value2'],'Key3':['value3'],'Key4':['value4']
    ,'Key5':['value5']
}

data2={'Key1':['value1','value4'],'Key2':['value2','value5'],'Key3':['value3'
,'value6']}
df1=pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2=pd.DataFrame(data2)
result = pd.concat([df1, df2.columns.to_frame().T, df2], ignore_index=True)
result.fillna(value='',inplace=True)    
print(result)

Here I am merging df1 and df2(after extracting the column names of df2,converts them into a dataframe with a single row, and transposes it. The result is a dataframe with the column names of df2 as its row values.
So output here is ->
Key1    Key2   Key3   Key4   Key5
value1 value2 value3 value4 value5
Key1    Key2   Key3   
value1 value2  value3
value4 value5  value6


The problem with this is that the columns are scalable so
result.loc[0.5]='Key1','Key2','Key3','','' doesn't seem to work.

Ok the we can do some modifications as follows -:  result = pd.concat([df1, df2.columns.to_frame().T, df2], ignore_index=True)
result.fillna(value='',inplace=True)
